# why does [df] tell me I have a full disk when root [du] tells me I've only filled the disk with ~500gb out of 5tb?

Tags: raspberry-pi, filesystems, disk-usage

I have a new 5tb disk in a FUSE filesystem which I guess is basically empty but df tells me otherwise. The filesystem on disk is `mergerfs`. The setup consists of 4x 5TB Seagate 5400rpm external drives, all which have been formatted with one partition as `ext4` using `fdisk`. I've tried going in as root and check with du and it told me roughly 500GB of space used.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -h /mnt/hdd/disk4
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       4.6T  4.3T  393M 100% /mnt/hdd/disk4

root@raspberrypi:~# du -sh /mnt/hdd/disk4
464G    /mnt/hdd/disk4
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: You mentioned FUSE. What's the filesystem on the problematic disk?

Comment: @roaima Yes, I'm using FUSE. The filesystem on disk is mergerfs. The setup consists of 4x 5TB Seagate 5400rpm external drives, all which have been formatted the same way using fdisk.

Comment: `fdisk` doesn't format; it creates the partition table ready for you to create filesystems. mergerfs uses those filesystems to create its merged result

Comment: OK, thank you. I'm not really sure what that information changes regarding the question. Could you please help me explain? The drives all have 1 partition each as ext4.

Comment: If you unmount the mergefs filesystem and mount each of the individual ext4 filesystems in turn, what usage do they show (`df` vs `du`)? Please add this infomation to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation I've run into before, although this is an extreme case in my experience. This usually happens when there are files that have been deleted from disk, so `du` doesn't report them, but they are still open inside a running process somewhere, so `df` considers that space used. The most frequent "offender" is logrotate not properly restarting logging processes, resulting in the following situation:

- Log files you see on disk may or may not be written to
- Log writing processes are writing to (possibly) the active log file (e.g. `app.log`) and to the previous day's log file (e.g. `2022-01-03-app.log`, when today is 2022-01-04), but the previous day's file is the compressed copy when viewed in an `ls` (e.g. `2022-01-03-app.log.gz`)
- When uncompressed, previous day's log file takes up significant space (multiple 10's of GBs)

In this particular example, the `logrotate` daemon rotated the previous day's log file at midnight, giving it a timestamp for the previous day, but didn't actually trigger a log restart by the process writing to it. It compressed the previous day's log file, then deleted the uncompressed file, but since the writing process still has the file handle open, `df` considers that space to be consumed.

The problem can usually be resolved by adding a `HUP` (SIGHUP) type directive to the logrotate configuration file, though in rare cases you have to actually restart the process in question as it doesn't respond to a HUP properly.

If this is the situation you're experiencing, once you find the process in question and restart it, your used space as reported by `df` will suddenly drop dramatically, and your `df` and `du` outputs will match.

Comment: Very interesting case. Thank you for that in-depth answer and clarification of that specific issue. Unfortiunately I can't seem to solve my issue when trying to look in to this. My best guess at this moment is that since it's a mechanical drive I'm guessing it might be a faulty one even though the drive is brand new.